# Sum multiple columns and rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I'm having big trouble on querying a database.

I have a table like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| name                                   | spent_1 | spent_2 | spent_3 |
+----------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| Category A                             |    NULL |  124000 |   10884 |
| Category A                             |    NULL |   25630 |    9779 |
| Category A                             |    NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category A                             |       0 |       0 |       0 |
| Category A                             |   75000 |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category A                             |    4000 |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category A                             |    2700 |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category B                             |   10585 |   76868 |   15037 |
| Category B                             |    NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category B                             |       0 |       0 |    NULL |
| Category B                             |    5500 |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |  100000 |    NULL |  140000 |
| Category C                             |  160000 |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |    NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |    NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |       0 |       0 |    NULL |
| Category C                             |    NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |  100000 |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |    NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |    NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |    NULL |    NULL |  102040 |
| Category C                             |    NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |    NULL |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |   75000 |    NULL |    NULL |
| Category C                             |   26000 |    NULL |    NULL |
+----------------------------------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want to sum all values in spent_1, spent_2, spent_3 for each category to end up with a table like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| name                                        | total_spent           |
+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Category A                                  | sum of all occurences |
+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Category B                                  | sum of all occurences |
+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Category C                                  | sum of all occurences |
+---------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: This is symptomatic of poor design. Consider if you can revise the schema

Comment: @Strawberry - actually the table shown is a result of a complex query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if this is optimal way but you can try this:

```
SELECT name, SUM(
IFNULL(spent_1, 0) + 
IFNULL(spent_2, 0) + 
IFNULL(spent_3, 0)) total_spent 
from tableName
group by name
```

As alternative you can use `COALESCE` (is ANSI standard) instead of `IFNULL` (is not):

```
SELECT name, SUM(
COALESCE(spent_1, 0) + 
COALESCE(spent_2, 0) + 
COALESCE(spent_3, 0)) total_spent 
from tableName
group by name
```